# Can EPD Python and MacPorts Python coexist on OS X (matplotlib)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, macports, enthought

I've been using MacPorts Python 2.6 on OS X 10.6. 
I am considering also installing the Enthought Python Distribution (EPD) on the same machine because it comes preconfigured with matplotlib and other nice data analysis and visualization packages.

Can the two Python distributions co-exist peacefully on the same machine? 
What potential problems will I have to look out for (e.g., environment variables)?

I know that building matplotlib through MacPorts is an option, but the process is lengthy (on the order of a full day) and there are open questions about compiling some dependencies on  64bit Intel.

I would like to know about the tradeoffs before committing to one of the two approaches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not an OSX user, so I can't say for certain, but you should be fine.

EPD bundles its own python interpreter and all required libraries.  The installer basically just extracts a tarball into a stand-alone folder.

The linux installer doesn't modify any environment variables (not even $PATH), so I assume the mac installer is similar.

(Because of this, you'll probably want to manually set up aliases to the EPD python/ipython/etc binaries so you can more easily call them without changing your $PATH.)

EPD really should be completely stand-alone, as far as I know. It should be safe to install along-side anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I've used EPD on Windows 7. It works great. Only stalled on me a couple of times with rather large data set.

I also use OSX, and was about to install EPD but hesitating a bit.

I think python 2.7.3 that comes with EPD (early 2013) will become the default python. Normally, upgrading to 2.7 from 2.6 should not be much of problem based on my personal experience. But I am a bit concerned to have 2 versions of 2.7 and what kind of impact it will have on using GAE SDK on my OSX. (Upgrading created a bit of hassle with GAE SKD.)

Here is what EPD readme says:

A full installation will install the following:
  * Python framework -- installed into:
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3

- Python applications -- installed into
    /Applications/Enthought
- System fixes -- makes the EPD Python your default one by adding lines to
  your .bash_profile to your path.

I think I will sleep on this.